# Transform incoming JSON keys with Ruby and Faraday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, faraday

I'm using Faraday to retrieve JSON encoded objects from a web service, but the web service uses horrible key strings for the key:value pairs, like 'Memo' where I want 'description' and 'projectManager' where I want 'manager'.

How can I transform the keys as they are retrieved by Faraday and inserted the result into a Ruby hash?

I'm hoping this is a solved problem, but it sure is hard to find. (I see a lot of posts asking about symbols being converted to strings in JSON.parse() ).

Comment: There are 2 ways, you either `gsub` the json string and replace keys you don't want with keys you want before parsing it, or you do that on the hash itself e.g `hsh[:manager] = hsh.delete[:projectManager]`

Comment: How big is your incoming JSON? Show us a small sample of the JSON, plus an example of the code you wrote to solve this, and explain how it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

consider mapping the data into Virtus objects

https://github.com/solnic/virtus

```
class Foo
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :manager, String
  attribute :description, String

  def self.map(json)
    # you only need to map the ones that differ
    new(json.merge!({
      manager: json["projectManager"],
      description: json["Memo"]
    })
  end
end
```

then loop through your data as needed (or create a top level virtus object if it makes sense)

```
payload = ... # json retrieved by Faraday as array of ruby hashes
foo_list = payload.map do |item|
  Foo.map(item)
end
```